# Получение идентификатора при сохранении записи (NHibernate)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, save

Что и как должно быть настроено в классе сущности, чтобы этот код работал корректно (сохранение сущности с использованием NHibernate)?

```
using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession(Common.DBpath))
{
    SomeClass entity = new SomeClass();
    int id = (int)session.Save(entity);
    MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
}
```

В настоящий момент у меня id всегда равно 0, хотя в БД, конечно, уникальный идентификатор.

Comment: У `entity` вашей должно заполниться свойство, отвечающее за ID

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но что это значит? Я предполагал, что СУБД сгенерирует ИД и я его использую для дальнейшей логики приложения.

Comment: У вас должен быть маппинг сущности на табличку базы данных. Там должен быть маппинг ключа таблицы. Вот он (ключ таблицы замапленный на свойство сущности) и заполняется при сохранении сущности. Если вам надо ID сущности до начала работы с ней - то стоит посмотреть в сторону разных генераторов, варианты описаны тут - http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator

Comment: Маппинг ключа есть. У меня, как видно из кода, создается просто некий экземпляр класса. Потом я хочу его сохранить в БД и сразу узнать - с каким ID он сохранился в базу? Не делать же в базу запрос на максимальное (последнее) ID сущности в таблице. Генераторами поигрался (до того как задать вопрос) - не помогло. Пробовал native - ничего не изменилось. Пробовал assigned - получил удивительный результат в БД сохранилась запись с ID = 0! Чего достичь собственно средствами СУБД, наверное, никогда не получится :)

Comment: Честно говоря, быть может, я и не ту задачу решаю, которую нужно. У меня две сущности, фактически имеют связь "многие ко многим", но я замапил это отношение, как рекомендует мануал по хибернейту, через две связи "многие к одному". К примеру, в связи "Ученик - Класс", я выбираю из базы Класс, создаю ученика (я не знаю его ID) и хочу сохранить запись в таблице отношений Ученик - Класс, но у меня не получается это сделать, поскольку я еще не знаю ID ученика. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Еще раз попробовал все генераторы. Больше всего подходил бы следующий маппинг ID: Id(x => x.Id).Column("id").GeneratedBy.Increment();   Но он возвращает следующий по очереди ID к имеющемуся в базе, а в БД уже была запись с таким ID и она была удалена, поэтому и сохранение не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено. Не работает через метод Flush(), но работает с использованием транзакции - BeginTransaction()/Commit(). В таком случае ID объекта обновляется. Кто-нибудь может объяснить почему так?